# Abort JUnit thread externally

Tags: java, junit

I'm writing a testing application that uses JUnit. We launch JUnit manually with a runnable class

```
public class MyLauncher implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        launchJunit();
    }

    private void launchJunit() {
        LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request().selectors(selectors).build();
        Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
        launcher.execute(request);
    }
}
```

using

```
public class MyApplication {

    public void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService pool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        ScheduledFuture<?> thread = null;
        thread = pool.schedule(new MyLauncher());

        //
        // do some magic
        //

        thread.cancel(true);
        // or
        pool.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

However, neither `thread.cancel()` or `pool.shutdownNow()` will interrupt the JUnit thread. Unless I use `System.exit(0)` at the end of my application, JUnit will keep running. Is there a way to interrupt the JUnit thread? I'm using JUnit extensions so I could hook into some callback if necessary.

Comment: Where exactly is using JUnit? I don't see some specifically annotation or assert statements.

Comment: `launcher.execute()` spins up JUnit and runs the tests supplied by `selectors` and the `LauncherDiscoveryBuilder`, which is part of JUnit. The actual unit tests are not relevant in this case. My question is specific to only the JUnit thread.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it out and to me, it seems that the thread gets interrupted by pool.shutdownNow(), but with a little delay.

You can use the method [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) to wait until it has terminated.

When I rearrange your code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ScheduledExecutorService pool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        ScheduledFuture<?> thread = null;
        MyLauncher myLauncher = new MyLauncher();
        thread = pool.schedule(myLauncher, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
        System.out.println("Number of threads: " + threadSet.size());


        thread.cancel(true);
        pool.shutdownNow();

        System.out.println("Waiting for thread to terminate...");
        pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
        System.out.println("Number of threads: " + threadSet.size());
}
```

I get the output:

> Number of threads: 6
>   Waiting for thread to terminate...
>   Number of threads: 5